# Find the roots of a polynomial in Matlab

Tags: discrete-mathematics, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations

I have a polynomial $f$ of order 15 and I want to find its roots.

For `solve(f==0)`, the answer is `Warning: Explicit solution could not be found`.

What can I do to compute the roots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to solve $f(x)=0$ where $f$ is a polynomial, you can use the [roots()](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/roots.html) function in Matlab.

**Example**
Let $f(x)= x^{15}-2x^{14}+3x^{13}-4x^{12}+...+15x^1-16$, then define a vector $v$ as the vector of all the coefficients in decreasing order, i.e.

```
v = [1 -2 3 -4 5 -6 7 -8 9 -10 11 -12 13 -14 15 -16]
```

then *roots(v)* returns all roots of $f$

```
roots(v)
ans =

   1.2367 + 0.0000i
   1.1461 + 0.4609i
   1.1461 - 0.4609i
   0.8883 + 0.8525i
   0.8883 - 0.8525i
   0.5027 + 1.1159i
   0.5027 - 1.1159i
   0.0489 + 1.2119i
   0.0489 - 1.2119i
  -0.4030 + 1.1270i
  -0.4030 - 1.1270i
  -0.7812 + 0.8754i
  -0.7812 - 0.8754i
  -1.0202 + 0.4962i
  -1.0202 - 0.4962i
```

which are complex in this case.

Comment: I assumed that, when you said "you can not give the coefficients" you meant that you didn't want to write them down, but you would be able to produce them and write them down in the vector $v$